# Scala: Composition with parameterless method

Tags: scala

I am trying to use function composition, but I am not sure how to make this work with parameterless methods.

The following code functionally does what I need it to do:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

def buildWeekReport(forDay: DateTime, where: String) = {

  case class ReportPeriod(from: DateTime, to: DateTime)

  def calculateLastWeek(day: DateTime) = ReportPeriod(day.minus(7), day)

  def renderPeriod(period: ReportPeriod) = s" we pretend to store $period to $where"

  (calculateLastWeek _ andThen renderPeriod)(forDay)
}
```

Here is how I would like to express that functionality:

```
def buildWeekReport3(forDay: DateTime, where: String) = {

  case class ReportPeriod(from: DateTime, to: DateTime)

  def calculateLastWeek() = ReportPeriod(forDay.minus(7), forDay)

  def renderPeriod(period: ReportPeriod) = s" we pretend to store $period to $outputPath"

  calculateLastWeek _ andThen renderPeriod
}

buildWeekReport3(DateTime.now, "c:/temp")
```

Perhaps my question should be, why is there no andThen method defined on Function0?

**As suggested, changing the signature to a Function1 (by using a unit: Unit parameter) seems like the least involved "fix".**

Another, more involved workaround, would have been something such as:

```
case class MyFunction0[+R](val fn0: Function0[R]) {
  def andThen[A](g: (R) ⇒ A): () ⇒ A = () => g(fn0())
}

implicit def fn0ToMyFn0[R](fn0: Function0[R]) = new MyFunction0(fn0)

def buildWeekReport4(forDay: DateTime, where: String) = {

  case class ReportPeriod(from: DateTime, to: DateTime)

  def calculateLastWeek = ReportPeriod(forDay.minus(7), forDay)

  def renderPeriod(period: ReportPeriod) = s" we pretend to store $period to $where"


  (calculateLastWeek _ andThen renderPeriod)()
}

buildWeekReport4(DateTime.now, "c:/temp4")
```

Comment: Try `def calculateLastWeek(unit:Unit)`

Answer (score 1):

`andThen` is the function that accepts two arguments of `Function1` type, so you have to represent you functions as `Function1`

It can be done by redefining `calculateLastWeek` as

`def calculateLastWeek = (z: Unit) => ReportPeriod(forDay.minus(7), forDay)`

then you can write

```
  val x = calculateLastWeek andThen renderPeriod
  x()
```

Comment: `(calculateLastWeek andThen renderPeriod)()` to really call it

Answer (score 1):

Are you not just looking for `renderPeriod(calculateLastWeek)`? Unless this is for some kind of DSL.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps my question should be, why is there no andThen method defined on Function0?

`andThen` is only defined on `Function1` because it uses the outcome of the first function as an argument to the second. If `Function0` would have an `andThen` method the result of the first method would be lost.

Comment: This is not correct. Function1 andThen is `{ x => g(apply(x)) }`. And for Function0 could be `{() => g(apply()))}`

Comment: If `g` is a `Function0` it would take 0 arguments in which case `g(apply(x))` would not be correct.

Comment: simply define g as `g: R => A` where R is the return type of F0 like in F1 and it would work. Esle it would not work in F1 as well.

Comment: You are correct, this would work. But in this case the `andThen` function on `Function0` would take a `Function1` as argument. This is possible but it would break the symmetry.

Comment: For any arity an `andThen` would have to take a F1, cos there is alwas one return value.